# Marionette async model fetching not working as expected

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, marionette

I'm running into a weird issue. I have a Marionette module responsible for fetching data, which is exposed through `Backbone.Wreqr` Request/Response system. For my projects it looks like this (CoffeeScript):

```
@App.module 'Entities', (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class Entities.Project extends Backbone.Model
        urlRoot: '/api/project'

    class Entities.ProjectsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
        model: Entities.Project
        url: '/api/projects.json'

    API =
        getProjectEntities: ->
            projects = new Entities.ProjectsCollection
            projects.fetch()
            projects

        getProject: (project) ->
            project = new Entities.Project({ id: project });
            project.fetch()
            project


    App.reqres.setHandler 'project:entities', ->
        API.getProjectEntities()

    App.reqres.setHandler 'project:entity', (project) ->
        API.getProject(project)
```

For the collection this works entirely as expected. Data is fetched, and when I pass it to a `Marionette.CompositeView` the view is rendered just fine.

I'm fleshing out a detail-page for these projects now, and all is not well. When I request a specific model by instantiating a new model `currentProject = App.request 'project:entity', project`, and then pass it on to a `Marionette.ItemView`, the ItemView parses its template before the model is fetched, causing an `Uncaught reference error` because the variables in my template haven't been declared yet... Any idea what's going on here?

My template is for now extremely simple:

```
    <script id="project_detail_template" type="text/template">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <p><%= title %></p>
    </script>
```

*Edit*: Ok, apparently I'm doing more things wrong here, because when I log out this model to the console, all it has attribute-wise is its `id`. If someone could set me in the right direction that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `fetch` and then immediately returning the `project` object, without waiting for the async `fetch` to complete.

Instead of returning the `project` object, return `project.fetch()` as this will return a promise. Then you can `.then` the value, ensuring it is available:

```
@App.module 'Entities', (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class Entities.Project extends Backbone.Model
        urlRoot: '/api/project'

    class Entities.ProjectsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
        model: Entities.Project
        url: '/api/projects.json'

    API =
        getProjectEntities: ->
            projects = new Entities.ProjectsCollection
            projects.fetch()

        getProject: (project) ->
            project = new Entities.Project({ id: project });
            project.fetch()


    App.reqres.setHandler 'project:entities', ->
        API.getProjectEntities()

    App.reqres.setHandler 'project:entity', (project) ->
        API.getProject(project)
```

When making the call through reqres, you'll get a promise back.

```
App.request("project:entity", someId, function (promise){

  // wait for the project to finish loading

  $.when(promise).then(function(project){
    // do stuff with your project, here
  });

});
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but now when I log out my response it just outputs raw JSON instead of an actual model instance... I'm sure I'm missing a larger concept here...

Comment: I've made a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/3059b400661dd99cec89

Comment: oh, right. sorry. i forgot that it doesn't return the model from that promise. you'll need to wrap your fetch in a promise of it's own. example here: https://github.com/marionettejs/bbclonemail/blob/master/public/javascripts/bbclonemail/contacts/contacts.js#L28-L46

Comment: I have no idea what's going on there... I'm still learning all this. If you have time to elaborate it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Also: why does this work on my collection, but not on my model? Are they handled differently?

Comment: Ah I got it now! The callback structure you tried to illustrate wasn't in place in my entities yet. I've updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/3059b400661dd99cec89